# how to get session data in angular2

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, angular

tried

```
 getLogin():Observable<Login>
  {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');                
    let options = new RequestOptions({
    method: RequestMethod.Post,
   url: "Attend.aspx/getLogin",                   
   headers: this.headers,
   body:{}
   });
            return this._http.request(new Request(options)).retry(2)
            .map((response: Response) => JSON.parse(response.text()))
            .do(data => console.log('getFacultyList: ' + data))
             .catch(this.handleError);              
   }
```

tried following way but its static method so i cannot access session data

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
  public static string getLogin()
  { 
    return "session data ";
  }
```

Following way I used in old project to get C# session data in JavaScript.

```
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var programme = "<%= Session["tmtbl_programname"]%>";
      var locate   = "<%= Session["tmtbl_location"] %>";
     </script>
```

**Question**

1)how to use `session data in angular2`?

2)how to `get Session data which are assign in C# code which use in  angular2`

Comment: are you talking about LocalStorage ?..

Comment: actual  I created session in C# code like **Session["user"] =pravin**  this I want to access because my project not single page application so after login redirect to angular2 index page

Comment: how to pass session data in such condition same process in old project I need session  in javascript i used script code which I given in question so like that how to access